# Neo4j Cypher non-shared descendant nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j application I have a composite `Decision` node. Each `Decision` can have an unlimited number and depth of descendant `Decision` nodes.

I have a Cypher query that returns descendant decision id's for a certain parent decision id:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:CONTAINS*]->(descendantDecision) 
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} 
RETURN id(descendantDecision) as id
```

I need to modify this function in order to return only non-shared descendant decision nodes id's.

For example I have a following hierarchy:

[image]

The new Cypher query for parent `D3` `{decisionId}` must return following descendant decisions id's : `D4`, `D6`, `D7`, `D8`

Please note that shared node with id `D7`(shared with `D4` and `D8`) must be returned because this node is only shared inside of `D3` inner hierarchy but shared node with id `D5` must not be returned because it is shared with some other node (`D9`) from an external hierarchy to `D3`.

So, the following nodes(marked with a green sign - `D4`, `D6`, `D7`, `D8`) must be returned:

[image]

Please help me to create this new Cypher query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant criteria here is that each member of the result set must only have inbound relationships from nodes being descendents of the original node. So the statement looks like:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendantDecision)  
WHERE d.name=3  
WITH collect(descendantDecision) AS allDescendants
UNWIND allDescendants AS descendant 
MATCH (descendant)<-[:CONTAINS]-(parent)  
WITH descendant, collect(parent) AS parents, allDescendants
WHERE ALL (x IN parents WHERE x IN allDescendants)  // check if all inbound start at a descendant
RETURN descendant
```

For completeness I've created a neo4j console setup for this: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ufyu0u

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative variant to @sarmbruster's suggestion:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendantDecision)
WHERE d.name=3
WITH collect(DISTINCT descendantDecision) AS allDescendants 
UNWIND allDescendants AS descendant
WITH allDescendants, descendant
WHERE ALL (p IN (descendant)<-[:CONTAINS]-() 
             WHERE last(nodes(p)) IN allDescendants)
RETURN descendant
```